# Como adicionar um Menu num único Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragment, menu

Eu tenho 3 Fragments e todos eles numa só Activity mãe. Eu quero o seguinte menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <item
        android:title="@string/tipo_de_mapa_menu"

        >

        <menu>

             <group
                android:checkableBehavior="single"
                >

                    <item
                        android:id="@+id/terreno_maptype"
                        android:title="@string/terreno_map_type"
                        />

                    <item
                        android:id="@+id/satelite_maptype"
                        android:title="@string/satelite_map_type"
                        />

                    <item
                        android:id="@+id/hibrido_maptype"
                        android:title="@string/hibrido_map_type"
                        />


             </group>

        </menu>


    </item>


    <item
        android:id="@+id/sobre_menu"
        android:title="@string/sobre_menu"
        />

</menu>
```

neste Fragment:

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback  {

    private GoogleMap map;
    private View view = null;
    private FloatingActionButton fab;
    private LatLng yourCar;

    public MapFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment, container, false);

        setupComps();

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    }


    public void setupComps() {

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        fab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(fabListener);


    }

    View.OnClickListener fabListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            centralizarACameraNoVeiculo();

        }
    };



    public void configurarMapa() {

        map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
        map.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);

    }

    public void alterarTipoParaHibrido() {

        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

    }

    public void alterarTipoParaTerreno() {

        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);

    }

    public void alterarTipoParaSatelite() {

        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);

    }

    public void centralizarACameraNoVeiculo() {


        CameraPosition camera = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(yourCar)
                .zoom(15)
                .build();

        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(camera));



        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Botão clicado...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    public void apontarOMarker() {

        // Add a marker in Maputo, Mozambique and move the camera
        yourCar = new LatLng(-25.962803, 32.583162);
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(yourCar).title("Seu veículo está aqui"));

        alterarTipoParaHibrido();

        CameraPosition position = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(yourCar)
                .zoom(15)
                .build();
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(position));

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        map = googleMap;

        apontarOMarker();

        configurarMapa();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

        menu.clear();
        getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_actvity_menu, menu);

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {


            case  R.id.terreno_maptype:
                //TODO

                item.setChecked(true);

                alterarTipoParaTerreno();



                break;

            case R.id.satelite_maptype:

                //TODO

                item.setChecked(true);
                alterarTipoParaSatelite();

                break;


            case R.id.hibrido_maptype:

                item.setChecked(true);
                alterarTipoParaHibrido();

                //TODO

                break;



            case R.id.sobre_menu:

                Intent sobre = new Intent(getContext(), SobreActivity.class);
                startActivity(sobre);

                break;

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Mas, o problema é que este menu aparece quando nos restantes Fragments mesmo sem os menus tenham os métodos `onCreateOptionsMenu()` e o `onOptionsItemSelected()`

A Activity mãe:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FragmentManager fragMan;
    private FragmentTransaction ftrans;

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.btm_route:
                    // TODO

                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.rota_fragment_titulo_actionBar);

                    getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.fragment, new RotaFragment())
                            .commit();


                    return true;
                case R.id.btm_localizacao:
                    // TODO

                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.localizacao_fragment_titulo_actionBar);


                    getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.fragment, new MapFragment())
                            .commit();

                    return true;
                case R.id.btm_fuel:
                    // TODO

                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.fuel_fragment_titulo_actionBar);


                    getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.fragment, new FuelFragment())
                            .commit();

                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };



    public void setupComps() {

        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.btm_localizacao);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

    }


    public void configurarFragments() {

        fragMan = getSupportFragmentManager();
        ftrans = fragMan.beginTransaction();

        ftrans.add(R.id.fragment, new MapFragment(), "MapaFragmento");
        ftrans.commitAllowingStateLoss();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.localizacao_fragment_titulo_actionBar);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       // configurarFragments();


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {


            //configurarFragments();

            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment, new MapFragment())
                    .commit();


        }

        setupComps();



    }


}
```

Como faço para que esse menu apareça apenas no Fragment especificado?

Comment: Vc tentou invocar o `menu.clear()` no `onCreateOptionsMenu` dos outros fragments?

Comment: Isso também não resulta!